# How to map paste from sysbuffer in insert mode?

Tags: vim

I'm trying this `map! <S-C-V> <C-r-*>`, but it doesn't work. Is there a way, to map Ctrl+r+* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mapping's *right-hand side*, the command to paste the X selection consists of **two keypresses**, which must be written `<C-r>` followed by `*` (normal keys do not require the special `<X-y>` notation):

```
noremap! <S-C-V> <C-r>*
```

Also, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.